# Make code faster in Python dict

Tags: python

I have this piece of code:

```
if pair.direction == "F1R2" or pair.direction == "R2F1":
    key = float(str(pair.r1.reference_id)+str(orient[pair.direction])+"."+str(pair.r1.pos))
    value = float(str(pair.r2.reference_id)+str(orient[pair.direction])+"."+str(pair.r2.pos+pair.frside))
elif pair.direction == "F1F2" or pair.direction == "F2F1":
    key = float(str(pair.r1.reference_id)+str(orient[pair.direction])+"."+str(pair.r1.pos))
    value = float(str(pair.r2.reference_id)+str(orient[pair.direction])+"."+str(pair.r2.pos))
elif pair.direction == "R1R2" or pair.direction == "R2R1":
    key = float(str(pair.r1.reference_id)+str(orient[pair.direction])+"."+str(pair.r1.pos+pair.frside))
    value = float(str(pair.r2.reference_id)+str(orient[pair.direction])+"."+str(pair.r2.pos+pair.frside))
else: #F2R1 or R1F2
    key = float(str(pair.r1.reference_id)+str(orient[pair.direction])+"."+str(pair.r1.pos+pair.frside))
    value = float(str(pair.r2.reference_id)+str(orient[pair.direction])+"."+str(pair.r2.pos))
if pair.r1.reference_id in dupes:
    if key in dupes[pair.r1.reference_id]:
        #duplicate!!!
        outputs["duplicates"].put([attr1,attr2])
        continue
    else:
        dupes[pair.r1.reference_id][key] = value
else: #not a dup
    dupes[pair.r1.reference_id] = {key: value}
```

In dictionary `dupes`, it may contain ~100M keys. Do you know a faster way to search or relating `key` and `value` variables? Both `key` and `value` variables are `floats`.

Comment: Why do you think the size of `dupes` is relevant? Dictionaries are constant-time lookup.

Comment: Your problem is one of memory, not dictionary lookup speed. 100M strings surely push your process into swap. Use a database instead; Python comes with SQLite included.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: well, 100M strings plus associated values is going to take up a sizeable amount of memory.

Comment: @user2979409: on my 64-bit Mac, a Python `float` object requires 24 bytes of memory. 100M of those requires 2GB+ just for those values. Then there is the gigantic hash table for the outer dictionary plus however many nested dictionaries you have, with at least 100M references to those objects (8 bytes each).

Comment: @user2979409: and I didn't even get started on the values; if those are floats too, then you need another 2GB+ for those values. You are already exceeding the per-process memory limits of most OSes.